# Site problem with AWS error 403 forbidden

Tags: amazon-web-services

I did everything by the book, but still getting forbidden when I try to reach my site.

I registered a domain trough `route53`and added both buckets `www.nadavrosenbergdev.com` and `nadavrosenbergdev.com` but still getting the error. I also tryied adding bucket policy which did not work.

Can someone please help.

It seems too difficult and I might disband `AWS` and move to an easier host and solutions (there are many of them). A friend told me `AWS` is the best but for some reason, it is very unclear.

Please help.

Comment: the worst part of it , is that i have to pay for extra support on AWS... i am just trying it out dont mind spending a few bucks on it , but WOW SUPPORT COSTS MONEY ON AWS.. i think i made a mistake by choosing them and listening to a friend.

Comment: Can you check whether your bucket is public or not?

Comment: https://ibb.co/Rgz7CbB
is this what you mean ?

Comment: What guide have you used? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html ?

Comment: this is the exact one i did.

Comment: If you open the site, using the bucket url instead of the CNAME from Route53, do you still get Forbidden?

Comment: Alex what do you mean?

Comment: im sorry this is very new to me